# How to call a method from another method to get the withdrawal value divide into $20 notes and $50 notes

Tags: java

currently I'm working on an assignment where I take the user's input, which is the amount of money that they want to withdraw and the output will be that money divide into bills of 20 and bills of 50. I have complete the conditions for other cases but I got stuck here, with numbers 110 and 190. I'm unable to call the getValue method from the run method, can you guys help me

```
 import java.util.Scanner;
    
    public class Int{
        public static int Input(){
            Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
            int result;
            return result= input.nextInt();
        }
        static void getValue(){
            int money = Input();
            int bill20, bill50;
            int x = 0, y = 0;
            bill50 = (money/50);
                for(int i=1; i<= (money/50); i++){
                    y++;
                }
            bill20 = (money-(y*50))/20;
                for(int i=1; i<=bill20; i++){
                    x++;
                }
        System.out.println("Here is " + x + " $20 notes and "+y+ " $50 notes. ");
        }
        
        public static void run(){
            System.out.print("Enter the amount of money: ");
            int money = Input();
            int bill20, bill50;
            int x = 0, y = 0;
            if(money > 100 && money % 50 != 0 && money % 20 != 0 ){
                bill50 = (money/50)-1;
                for(int i=1; i<=bill50; i++){
                    y++;
                }
                bill20 = (money-(y*50))/20;
                for(int i=1; i<=bill20; i++){
                    x++;
                }
                int sum = (x*20)+(y*50);
                if (sum == money){
                    System.out.println("Here is " + x + " $20 notes and "+y+ " $50 notes. ");
                } else{
                    getValue(); //Something went wrong here
                }
            }
        }
        //Printing the run method
        public static void main(String[] args){
            run();
        }
    }
```

Output:

Enter the amount of money: 110
Here is 3 $20 notes and 1 $50 notes.

Enter the amount of money: 190

When I entered 190, the system didn't print anything

Comment: For a start I would assume that your `if` should be a `while`.  Also try using a debugger to step through your code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Buddy your issue is fixed, try this code

```
import java.util.Scanner;
    
    class Int{
        int result;
        public void Input(){
            System.out.printf("Enter the money : ");
            Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
            result= input.nextInt();
        }
        public void getValue(){
            int money = result;
            int bill20, bill50;
            int x = 0, y = 0;
            bill50 = (money/50);
                for(int i=1; i<= (money/50); i++){
                    y++;
                }
            bill20 = (money-(y*50))/20;
                for(int i=1; i<=bill20; i++){
                    x++;
                }
        System.out.println("Here is " + x + " $20 notes and "+y+ " $50 notes. ");
        }
        
        public void run(){
            System.out.print("Enter the amount of money: ");
            int money = result;
            int bill20, bill50;
            int x = 0, y = 0;
            if(money > 100 && money % 50 != 0 && money % 20 != 0 ){
                bill50 = (money/50)-1;
                for(int i=1; i<=bill50; i++){
                    y++;
                }
                bill20 = (money-(y*50))/20;
                for(int i=1; i<=bill20; i++){
                    x++;
                }
                int sum = (x*20)+(y*50);
                if (sum == money){
                    System.out.println("Here is " + x + " $20 notes and "+y+ " $50 notes. ");
                } else{
                    getValue(); //Something went wrong here
                }
            }
        }
        //Printing the run method
        public static void main(String[] args){
            Int i = new Int();
            i.Input();
            i.getValue();
            i.run();
        }
    }
```

Comment: glad to  help you. If this answer worked, Please click on accept answer